# how to select the records of specific timespan?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to select the records from table that lies in between a specific time span. for example select record_name from tbl_name where date (is between now and 10 minutes earlier)? hope this rough query will explain my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use [**`DATE_ADD`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
select record_name 
from tbl_name 
where `date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -10 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

Comment: its saying unknown column NOW??

Comment: @baig772 try it again, I forgot to add parenthesis in `NOW` on `DATE_ADD`

Comment: yes i corrected it but its showing empty result set, while inserting in db, i set the column type to **date time** and inserted in this column using `NOW()`

Comment: uhmm, try interchanging the values of `BETWEEN`, `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -10 MINUTE) AND NOW()`

Comment: yes it worked, kindly edit your answer accordingly so i will accept it. thanks to you boss :)